# I need to set a pdf file from controller using jQuery and JavaScript ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I found this example that opens in a modal or pop ups a PDF file .

[Example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/1261/)
This example of my Javascript code that sets the pdf file by taking it from the folder, but I need to display the pdf by calling a controller that converts from bytes to pdf and returns the file, I need to set this in this code but I don't know how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var fileName = "Example.pdf";
            $("#btnShow").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    title: fileName,
                    width: 1440, 
                    height: 800,
                    buttons: {
                        Close: function () {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    open: function () {
var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
                        object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href=\"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                        object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                        object += "</object>";
                        object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Files/" + fileName + "#view=fitV");
                        $("#dialog").html(object);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input id="btnShow" type="button" value="@Model.documentType" />
    <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Previously I called the controller using URL Action as below but I need to set this in the code above.

```
src="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Home", new { Model.Id })"
```

Controller

```
public async Task < ActionResult > GetPDF(Guid id) {

    var vm = new ViewModels.Home.AttachmentViewModel();

    var result = vm.GetServiceAttachment(id);
    byte[] file;
    foreach(var attachment in result) {
        byte[] termsPdf = attachment.File;
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyFile.pdf");

    }
    return null;
}
```